# Issue converting double to boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I am working on a project in my Java class that is using multiple classes as well as GUI (not sure if that info is relevant). My group partner and I have come across an issue though. We have a Validator class, that should validate a "SSN" but we are continuously given the error:

```
java:146: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to boolean
                    if(Validator.isValidSSN(jTextFieldEmpSSN)){
```

Now obviously java:146 is the line. the code we have for each class is:

employeeUI class (the one showing the error):

```
private void jButtonEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
        Employee e=new Employee();

        if(Validator.isValidName(jTextFieldEmpFirst)){
            if(Validator.isValidName(jTextFieldEmpLast)){
               if(Validator.isValidEmail(jTextFieldEmpEmail)){
                    if(Validator.isValidSSN(jTextFieldEmpSSN)){
        e.setFirstName(jTextFieldEmpFirst.getText());
        e.setLastName(jTextFieldEmpLast.getText());
        e.setEmailAdd(jTextFieldEmpEmail.getText());
        e.setSSN(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldEmpSSN.getText()));
}}}}
```

and the Validator class for isValidSSN is:

```
public static double isValidSSN(JTextField textfield)
{
    double number = 0;
    boolean inRange = false;
    while(!inRange)
    {
        number = Double.parseDouble(textfield.getText());
        if (number >= 100000000 && number <= 999999999) 
        {
            inRange = true;

        } else {}
    } 

    return number;
}
```

We have been beating our head on how to fix this for quite some time, but are coming up at a loss. Are we missing something? we would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Why not simply have `isValidSSN` return a boolean value? Makes no sense to return a double in this situation.

Comment: Also if you ever find yourself writing `else {}`, just delete that part. You can have an `if` without and `else`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's the answer the OP needs, obviously. Be kind, they posted a good student question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right @JohnKugelman, it's just such a strange question

Comment: OP, a test of validity should simply return a boolean -- true if the condition is valid, false if it isn't. Simple, efficient and correct.

Comment: We're not born knowing how booleans work, or the not-so-obvious distinction between parsing and validation. Rules like "methods named `isXXX` should return booleans" become so ingrained that we forget what it's like not to know them. It reminds me of how you can mess up a tennis pro by asking them to explain the mechanics of a simple forehand stroke. They don't consciously think at that level any more; it's all muscle memory to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I ask, "Is 123-45-6789" a valid SSN?" you wouldn't reply "123456789.0", would you? You'd give me a yes or a no. By returning `double` your method is doing the former. It's responding with a number instead of an answer to the question.

A good rule of thumb is that methods starting with `is` or `has` should return `boolean`s. "Is this a valid SSN?" is a yes/no question, so `isValidSSN` should return the programming equivalent of yes/no.

```
public static boolean isValidSSN(JTextField textfield)
```

There are a couple of other design points here:

- The loop isn't necessary. The SSN is either valid or it isn't.
- A text field is not itself an SSN. It holds some text, and that text is the SSN. Rather than taking a text field and looking up the text in the field with `getText()`, it'd be better to have `isValidSSN` take the text directly. Let the *caller* extract the text from the text field.

  In broader terms this is known as the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Every method should ideally do just one thing.

Result:

```
public static boolean isValidSSN(String ssn) {
    double number = Double.parseDouble(ssn);

    if (number >= 100000000 && number <= 999999999) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

P.S. If I don't mention it someone will surely comment that the `if` and `else` blocks aren't necessary; one can return the `if` result directly. They would be right, though I consider it a bit of an advanced trick. It would look like so:

```
public static boolean isValidSSN(String ssn) {
    double number = Double.parseDouble(ssn);
    return number >= 100000000 && number <= 999999999;
}
```

Comment: Important to note: the loop, as originally written, also presented an **infinite loop** danger.